# Calling AWS APIGateway with a Cognito user pool

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have a REST API configured on my AWS account using AWS APIGateway. The REST API uses a Cognito Authorizer for authentication.

I am using a Python Script to interact with the API. In this Python script, I managed to authenticate a user. For the sake of informatio, here is how I do it handling the case where the user needs to update its password (first authentication) :

```
region = 'eu-west-1'
cognito = boto3.client('cognito-idp', region)

clientId = 'abcdefghijk27261819'
username = "myUsername"
password = "myPassword"

response = cognito.initiate_auth(AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH', AuthParameters={"USERNAME": username,
        "PASSWORD": password}, ClientId = clientId)

try : 
    response['ChallengeName']
    response = cognito.respond_to_auth_challenge(ClientId=clientId, ChallengeName=response['ChallengeName'], Session=response['Session'],
    ChallengeResponses={"USERNAME": username,
        "NEW_PASSWORD": "myNewPassword"})
except KeyError:
    pass

# store credentials
accessToken = response['AuthenticationResult']['AccessToken']
idToken = response['AuthenticationResult']['IdToken']
```

I am able to verify that the identity token `idToken` is the one expected by the API through the APIGateway console :

[image]

[image]

However, even though the token seems to be ok, I can't call the API.

I tried two calls :

```
HOST = "https://<APIID>.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
STAGE = "dev"
BASE_URL = f"{HOST}/{STAGE}"

r = requests.post(f"{BASE_URL}/S3Operations/CreateSimulationBucket", headers={"Authorization": idToken}) # the call I want
r = requests.post(f"{BASE_URL}", headers={"Authorization": idToken}) # the test call
```

and both calls return an error :

```
# first call
{'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '23', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Date': 'Tue, 22 Jun 2021 07:36:47 GMT', 'x-amzn-RequestId': 'd87ee0c8-d004-4199-8974-1727830c9f25', 'x-amzn-ErrorType': 'ForbiddenException', 'x-amz-apigw-id': 'BUPqaFQcDoEF3Xg=', 'X-Cache': 'Error from cloudfront', 'Via': '1.1 5e828cc6ff056cb59ec35c3467ec45f5.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)', 'X-Amz-Cf-Pop': 'AMS1-C1', 'X-Amz-Cf-Id': '6sbLUxCEmUWQYTWD6BHAommN6eTVieLmL-6XOJh30fNW-IhdcztJIQ=='}
# second call
{'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '1379', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Date': 'Tue, 22 Jun 2021 07:45:19 GMT', 'x-amzn-RequestId': 'b69a442e-3b3c-4447-bec8-8eff344ac7cb', 'x-amzn-ErrorType': 'IncompleteSignatureException', 'x-amz-apigw-id': 'BUQ6bFLqjoEFjhA=', 'X-Cache': 'Error from cloudfront', 'Via': '1.1 043fc2faaa02eeb59193e3fa300adb6b.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)', 'X-Amz-Cf-Pop': 'AMS1-C1', 'X-Amz-Cf-Id': '8btFflDUE2I7LxiKbvnmreOE-oKrIwbudgORbWaRrASNUmIPdYtwYQ=='}
```

My questions are :

1. Why the first call return a `ForbiddenException` ? I believe my paths are correctly configured : [image]
2. Why the second call returns a `IncompleteSignatureException` ?

##### PROGRESS

For question 1. Actually, I could find information on AWS documentation page [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-troubleshoot-403-forbidden/) and was able to understand I simply called an unauthorized method.

For question 2. I was able to diagnose the issue more precisely through the use of API Gateway responses. As shown below, I crafted custom messages for all possible issues

[image: api_gateway_custom_responses]

And I was able to find out that the issue was a non-provided API Key. Indeed, my API has a UsagePlan and therefore requires an API Key.

I have modified my script to get this API Key as shown below

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='my-profile')

region = 'eu-west-1' # or 'us-west-1' or whatever
cognito = session.client('cognito-idp', region)
apigw = session.client('apigateway', region)

# Cognito information
cognito_userpool_client_id = 'abcdefghijk27261819'
cognito_username = 'my_username'
cognito_password = 'my_password|'

# API information
apigw_id = 'my_api_id'

def get_api_key(apigw_client, apigw_id):
    return apigw_client.get_api_key(apiKey=apigw_id, includeValue=True)['value']

response = cognito.initiate_auth(AuthFlow='USER_PASSWORD_AUTH', AuthParameters={"USERNAME": cognito_username,
        "PASSWORD": cognito_password}, ClientId = cognito_userpool_client_id)

# store credentials
accessToken = response['AuthenticationResult']['AccessToken']
idToken = response['AuthenticationResult']['IdToken']

# Call API
HOST = "https://<APIID>.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
STAGE = "dev"
BASE_URL = f"{HOST}/{STAGE}"

r = requests.post(f"{BASE_URL}/S3Operations/CreateSimulationBucket", headers={"Authorization": idToken, "x-api-key": get_api_key(apigw, apigw_id)})
```

despite these modifications I still receive the same error :

```
{'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Content-Length': '23', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Date': 'Tue, 22 Jun 2021 15:24:27 GMT', 'x-amzn-RequestId': '29743683-dbaf-4d60-bbae-8f2581e1c45a', 'x-amzn-ErrorType': 'ForbiddenException', 'x-amz-apigw-id': 'BVUKxF9FjoEFgbA=', 'issue': 'Invalid API Key', 'X-Cache': 'Error from cloudfront', 'Via': '1.1 bdba42cf1410fb617eeb4ffd3e0b9cb7.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)', 'X-Amz-Cf-Pop': 'AMS1-C1', 'X-Amz-Cf-Id': 'fMbbQSLlDd7OHErlPCoVNJRZM_P9mq5DYxgsfkJVy4sKHw9lijFYeA=='}
```

Comment: For the first question : I actually have found the reason : It's because it was a forbidden path. One can find useful information on AWS documentation (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-troubleshoot-403-forbidden/) to understand the messages.

Comment: For the second question : I was able to find more details using the API Gateway responses. I added custom responses to all possible events and find out that the issue comes from the fact that my API uses both Cognito & a usage plan i.e. an API key I did not provide.

I have modified my script to provide the API Key. But I still get the issue ... Updated the question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

have you deployed the api in api gateway? Have you tried constructing the api call in postman before you do it in python?

Comment: The API is deployed as part of my workflow. I have tried redeploying it. No changes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After some analysis, I was able to understand the issue.

For question 1. I could find information on AWS documentation page [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-troubleshoot-403-forbidden/) and was able to understand I simply called an unauthorized method i.e. calling the root of the API was not authorized because the root had no registered method/ressource.

For question 2. It took me some time to get to the heart of the problem. Indeed, by crafting custom gateway responses, I knew the problem was coming from an `Invalid API Key`. But this was in fact confusing because the real problem came from an invalid Authorizer !

Prior to solving the issue, here was my SAM template I was using for generating the resources :

```
  API:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: !Sub ${Env}
      # Authentication on the API will be performed via a Key
      Auth:
        Authorizers:
            CognitoAuthorizer:
              UserPoolArn: !GetAtt CognitoUserPool.Arn
        ApiKeyRequired: true 
        # this creates a key, a usage plan and associate them
        UsagePlan:
          CreateUsagePlan: PER_API
          UsagePlanName: !Sub ${Project}-${Env}-UsagePlan
```

So ... I define a Cognito Authorizer ... But I am not **actually using it**. I was able to identify that in the AWS API Gateway console. Going into the resource page I arrive to the path I want to call and I click on the `Method` box :

[image: apigateway_resource_page]

And I arrive at the page shown below. **Prior to the correction the `Authorization` field was `None` and that was causing my issue**

[image: apigateway_method_page]

Indeed ... I was making an API call with an Authorization header while there was no Authorization set on the method itself. Now I find it confusing that AWS does not send a more detailed error message and only send a `Invalid API key`. It took me a while to understand what was causing the issue because of that because I assumed there was an Authorizer on the method.

In order to solve the issue, I had to modify my SAM template as shown below and this modification allowed to set the Cognito Authorizer by default for all methods of the API and allowed me to make the call successfully :

```
  API:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: !Sub ${Env}
      # Authentication on the API will be performed via a Key
      Auth:
        Authorizers:
            CognitoAuthorizer:
              UserPoolArn: !GetAtt CognitoUserPool.Arn
        DefaultAuthorizer : CognitoAuthorizer
        ApiKeyRequired: true 
        # this creates a key, a usage plan and associate them
        UsagePlan:
          CreateUsagePlan: PER_API
          UsagePlanName: !Sub ${Project}-${Env}-UsagePlan
```

Notice the addition of the record `DefaultAuthorizer : CognitoAuthorizer`

Hope this will help others !